# How to give a rank using SPARQL?

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I have a question, how can we give a rank number using SPARQL? let's say, i have the example in the picture below. So, if `countKonsentrasi` has the highest number, the rank is 1, and so on.

[image: result]

Query that i have done but it didn't meet my needs:

```
String queryString =
                "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "
                + "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "
                + "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> "
                + "SELECT ?e (COUNT (?e) AS ?countKonsentrasi) "
                + " (COUNT (*) AS ?ranking) "
                + " WHERE { ?x rdfs:label  ?a;"
                + " rdfs:subClassOf ?b ."
                + " ?b rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing ."
                + " ?b rdfs:label ?e ."
                + " FILTER (regex(str(?a), '%s','i')) ."
                + "}"
                + "GROUP BY ?e "
                + "ORDER BY DESC (?countKonsentrasi) ";
```

is there a function for ranking like `RANK` in SPARQL?

**UPDATE**

I have tried with these new syntaxes. The column `ranking` shows 0 values.

```
String queryString =
                "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "
                + "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> "
                + "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> "
                + "SELECT ?e (COUNT (?e) AS ?countKonsentrasi) "
                + "(COUNT (?countKonsentrasi) AS ?ranking) "
                + " WHERE { ?x rdfs:label  ?a;"
                + " rdfs:subClassOf ?b ."
                + " ?b rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing ."
                + " ?b rdfs:label ?e ."
                + " FILTER (regex(str(?a), '%s','i')) ."
                + "}"
                + "GROUP BY ?e "
                + "ORDER BY DESC (?countKonsentrasi) LIMIT 5 ";
```

please help me. all helps i appreciate. thank you

Comment: no, there is no concept of "rank" in SPARQL nor is there anything like a "row number". I also don't understand why one would need it. Anything beyond SPARQL can be easliy achieved on the client side. At the end SPARQL is just a query language and not made for visualizing results to human

Comment: you query returns 0 because you would have to put it into a subquery, at the time you do the count the other count is not bound

Comment: So, is that still possible to do ranking using SPARQL?